# Why does my transistor turn "partially" off?

Tags: transistors, pcb-design, bjt

I'm trying to get IV curves of the BFP720FESD NPN bipolar junction transistor using a PXIe-4162 SMU.

I do a sweep of 0-3V on the collector for six base currents between 5uA and 85uA and measure the collector current.

DUT schematic (please ignore the erroneous JFET symbol representing a BJT):

[image]

[image]

Here is a picture of the setup:

[image]

In the picture of the setup, the SMPM3 has a loop back I attached between the signal and shell of the SMP connector so that the emitter is connected to ground.

Currently, my IV curves appear correct up until roughly the same percentage of their maximum Ic (or to the same slope depending on how you want to look at it). Please ignore the random disappearance of the curve in the graphs (I believe that's a separate issue).

[image]

For reference, here is an IV curve I took of the *same* transistor on a different board with no capacitors and with its emitter connected directly to ground on the PCB (no external loop back to ground).

[image]

[image]

**What is causing my IV curves to dramatically dip as if partially turned off and the other visible odd behavior?**

Comment: Please show board layout or a photo of the wiring (preferably both). Why was a JFET symbol used in the schematic? I suppose it doesn't matter for the question but it is confusing to see. Also, do you have any RF probing equipment available?

Comment: yeah I'll get that updated. The JFET symbol is what the schematic designer used... I suspect he was just being sloppy. I do have rf probing equipment like VNAs, Spectrum analyzers etc. It's not clear to me why the behavior in the RF domain would matter here. Could you elaborate? Hold tight for the updated info

Comment: Apart from a possible junction voltage breakdown, could your test fixture be breaking in to oscillation at those bias points? You only have to look at them sideways before they go squirrelly.

Comment: Ah, nice. I would merely suggest holding an RF probe (E or H near field) near the DUT while sweeping. (Note, given the 45GHz fT, you'll need a pretty good spec and probes.) Your answer most likely lies there.

Comment: Just a heads up that I added more info to the post. @glen_geek what do you mean that the test fixture would go into oscillation? This is a low frequency test. I don't believe a junction voltage breakdown is occurring because I'm well within the operating range according to the DS. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the posts by @glen_geek & Tim Williams: Suggest put a scope probe to view voltage at collector wrt emitter during the test, and adjust time-base to view relatively fast high-frequency oscillations (hundreds of kHz to tens of MHz).  This will prove HF oscillations as being the culprit if either (a) you see the oscillations on the scope, or (b) If the curves suddenly appear as normal (oscillation stopped by the scope parasitic C).  If you get no change yet see no oscillation, then at least the scope will prove out your data acquisition system.

Comment: @FabioBarone ok awesome. Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, put a scope probe to simultaneously view Ic & Vce as reported to the DAQ system.

Comment: Question: what exactly is a "PXIe-1095 SMU"?  Link?  And what does SMU stand for?

Comment: Sorry, PXIe-1095 is the chassis. What I meant is PXIe-4162 which the card installed which is a Source Measurement Unit. Here's a link https://www.ni.com/en-us/shop/model/pxie-4162.html

Comment: @Andrew Just because you say the test is low frequency doesn't mean you've set it up like that. These transistors have such wide bandwidth that parasitic inductances in a test fixture can easily turn them into oscillators. All I see on the pictures is very long cables and a lot of stuff that seems unnecessary. You'll want to lay a little test board with ferrite beads and RF chokes on every pin. That should keep it low frequency as you wish. The circuit won't know your intentions otherwise :)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this frequently when using excessively inductive (i.e. excessively long) cables to connect an SMU to the device under test. What's happening is that your SMU is oscillating, thus failing to reach its set point, so the measurement ends up being a fraction of what the true value would be.

Note that this is *not* your transistor turning off at higher collector voltages; this is either the collector voltage or the base current not actually being what the SMU thinks it is.

The simplest solution for this is to just shorten up the cables between the DUT and the SMU. If that's not an option, experiment with ferrite beads or resistors in series with the SMU's force (not sense) lines.

Comment: Shouldn’t this be avoided if you wait long enough before taking a measurement? I’m waiting about 1ms between steps

Comment: @Andrew This isn't ringing that dies down over time; this is oscillation that  is actively driven.

Comment: @Andrew Most SMUs can't deal with active RF oscillators very well. That's exactly what you got here.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Ah, right, it could be an oscillating DUT and not an oscillating SMU--the solution for both should be about the same, though.

Comment: So I looked at it with an 8ghz scope as a quick way to find oscillations and I definitely see a growing oscillation on the transistor that doesn’t work and no oscillation on the transistor that does. So the problem is definitely what @Hearth suggested. Why this one is oscillating and not the others on the same test setup is still a mystery to me. Thank you guys